# Activating an additional USB Wifi Adapter

Tags: android-things

I'm trying to add a wifi hotspot/access point to my raspberry pi running Android Things OS. I figured I would do this by adding an additional USB Wifi Adapter (Edimax EW-7811Un) and bridge it with the pi's internal wifi adapter.

Unfortunately, I am not linux savvy and am used to plug and play with windows and osx and not having to tweak any configurations manually!

After googling and running the various commands, I can see the adapter has been found.

Searching though `dmesg`, I can see the device...

```
[    4.131380] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    4.232604] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=7811
[    4.232616] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.232624] usb 1-1.4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[    4.232630] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    4.232637] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

Running `lusb` shows the device (004)...

```
rpi3:/ # lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811
```

But running `ifconfig /a` only shows the default hardware...

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:87:50:67  Driver brcmfmac_sdio
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: 2a00:23c4:7400:5c00:d848:e0c3:e997:182/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:d848:e0c3:e997:182/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:691d:ecb5:3fd2:94e0/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: 2a00:23c4:7400:5c00:7b46:c90f:599a:4551/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::29c9:aa36:a6bb:ddc5/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2121 errors:0 dropped:42 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:1775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:474636 TX bytes:889088 

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:33 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:33 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:4154 TX bytes:4154 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d2:05:32  Driver smsc95xx
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0
```

Can anyone advise whether Android Things OS can support an additional USB Wifi Adapter and if so, what I need to do to make the device active?

Comment: I do not believe that external networking hardware is currently supported on the platform.